# Change background color of MenuItem when clicked

Tags: android, menuitem

What is the correct way to change background color of a MenuItem? I would like to change it to sinalize that MenuItem is active but i didn't find how to do it.

By now, i'm changing icon for another one with different color but i don't need it, i just need to put some color on background when it is clicked.

Here is what i'm doing to change icon:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.mnNow:
        item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.now_icon_active);
        this.displayFragment(getNowFragment());
        break;
    default:
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can i change background color when it's clicked and keep the color until the user choose a new option?

Thank in advance.